# Get Current StackName in React Navigation 6 - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Please let ,me know how can i access current stack name , so i can navigate accordingly.
**Im using class based component , so i cannot use any of the hooks (useNavigation, useNavigationState, useRoute , useNavigation )** which RN community is suggesting a lot.

code snippet

```
 const currentStackName = this.props.navigation.getState().routes.find(
          (route) => route.state && route.state.index > 0
      );
     console.log('currentStackName', currentStackName);
```

Its always throwing undefined .

Please let me know how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can directly access it directly through this.props.navitaion. I did it by creating a ref for navigation in the NavigationContainer.

```
<NavigationContainer ref={ref => this.navigationRef = ref}>
{...code...}
</NavigationContainer>
```

You can store this ref in the reducers state and access it. After that you can console the below code to check

```
this.navigationRef?.getCurrentRoute().name
```